# Bash set parameter to variable which is a file

Tags: bash

As part of my script I'm trying to set up parameters. I'm trying to set 2nd parameter as a file that the rest of the script needs. I'm doing it like this:

```
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "file plz"
else
        file=$2
fi
```

and getting this error:

```
line 25: acctual_file{acctual_file}: No such file or directory
```

So how do I set up parameter in a way that if saves a variable of a file?

Comment: As part of investigation, please post your line 25th in your post and let us know then?

Comment: Yea, agree with @RavinderSingh13, your code doesn’t tell anything about your problem. The code you have posted should work fine without any changes.

Comment: Actually no, you may have a file consisting of spaces or newline or tab due to which only first half might be getting assigned to `file` and other half is getting treated as command, try `file="$2"`

Comment: @Mihir Good guess but actually no. Assignment's from variable to variable work correctly without quotes. You can try it yourself: `x="a b"; y=$x; declare -p y` prints `y="a b"`.